# regex - match HTML tags that don't contain @'s

Tags: jquery, regex, knockout.js

I am trying to write a function that determines if a string contains HTML tags. The following works fine:

```
self.containsTags = ko.computed(function() {
  if(/<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test(self.response())) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}, self);
```

Except, it also matches email addresses, eg. `<test@mail.com>` and `</test@mail.com>`. What I want it to do is to search through a string and if it finds a tag, return true UNLESS it is an email address as above - then continue searching through the string and return true if it finds an actual HTML tag or false if it doesn't.

Here is what I wrote, but unfortunately it doesn't work as I want it to:

```
self.containsTags = ko.computed(function() {
  if(/<[a-z][\s\S]((?!@).)*>/i.test(self.response())) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}, self);
```

Comment: And what if any DOM node attribute contains `@` as value?

Comment: In jQuery, i'd use: `return !!$('<div/>', {html: self.response()}).find('*').filter(function(){
        return this.nodeName.indexOf('@') === -1;
    }).length;`

Answer (score 2):

Whats about regex something like that ?

```
/<[^@<>]+>/i
```